# What is the correct descriptor type for Buffer<float4> when using an HLSL shader in Vulkan?

Tags: hlsl, vulkan

I'm trying to use an HLSL fragment shader in my Vulkan renderer. The shader reads a buffer:

```
layout(set=0, binding=3) Buffer<float4> pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius : register(t1);
```

I don't know what kind of descriptor I should use for that descriptor slot. I tried to use `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER` but the validation layer gives me the following error:

> Type mismatch on descriptor slot 0.3 (used as type ptr to const
>   uniform image(dim=5, sampled=1)) but descriptor of type
>   VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER

What is the correct descriptor type for `Buffer<float4>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick Googling, the [`Buffer` type in HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308064(v=vs.85).aspx) appears to represent what OpenGL would call a "buffer texture" and what Vulkan would call a "texel buffer". That is, a buffer which is interpreted as a 1D array of "pixels" of a particular format (hence the `<float4>` part).

The compiler is generating SPIR-V that matches this description: a `uniform` variable with a type created by `OpTypeImage`, with a dimension of `Buffer`(hence, [the "dim=5"](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/1.2/SPIRV.html#Dim) part of the error). Such a variable expects to be used against a descriptor of type `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER`. You will need to bind a `VkBufferView` to this descriptor, and the `VkBuffer` source of that view must allow for the `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER_BIT` usage.

And of course the memory backing that `VkBuffer` must allow such usage.